# Identify groups/sequences of repeating values

Tags: r

With an `input` data frame like below:

```
   ID val
1   1   c
2   1   c
3   1   d
4   1   d
5   1   c
6   2   b
7   2   c
8   2   d
9   2   b
10  2   c
11  2   b
12  3   a
13  3   b
14  3   a
15  3   b
16  3   a
17  4   b
18  4   a
19  4   b
20  5   f
21  5   f
```

I'm aiming at the following `output`:

```
   ID val idx
1   1   c   1
2   1   d   1
3   1   c   1
4   2   b   1
5   2   c   1
6   2   d   1
7   2   b   1
8   2   b   2
9   2   c   2
10  2   b   2
11  3   a   1
12  3   b   1
13  3   a   1
14  3   a   2
15  3   b   2
16  3   a   2
```

The logic is as follows:

- The column `val` consists of letters that are basically ordinal values (i.e. they are equal to `as.integer(factor(val))`).
- For each `val`, I would like to identify a sequence in which value turns into a higher one (e.g. `c -> d`, but it is not necessarily entirely consecutive, it could also be `c -> e`), and then returns to the initial value (e.g. `c -> d -> c`), disregarding any duplicates in-between.
- This explains why `ID` 4-5 are removed from final output.
- There are some cases where initial value is turning into a higher one and then repeating this cycle, like e.g. for `ID` 2-3. In these cases, I would like to reconstruct all sequences as separate ones with different indices (as shown in `idx` output column). This would necessarily copy some rows that are at the beginning of such cycles.

Any ideas on concise and fast ways of approaching this?

*Edit*

Unfortunately, the initial example for `input` was not of sufficient complexity - it gives false impression that first or last values are always relevant for the sequence.

This is not the case. Even with the `input` below which adds additional values at the beginning and the end of `ID` 1 and the end of `ID` 2 I would expect the same `output` as above:

```
   ID val
1   1   b
2   1   c
3   1   c
4   1   d
5   1   d
6   1   c
7   1   e
8   2   b
9   2   c
10  2   d
11  2   b
12  2   c
13  2   b
14  2   f
15  3   a
16  3   b
17  3   a
18  3   b
19  3   a
20  4   b
21  4   a
22  4   b
23  5   f
24  5   f
```

A letter is not the initiating part of the sequence just by appearing first; it is the subsequent duplication that retroactively establishes it as the beginning. The same goes for the last letter: it is not necessarily part of the sequence if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with this approach which is perhaps not the most condensed code-golf-ey answer, but I think it is somewhat readable and breaks your problem down into smaller steps.

The trick is really just to identify those rows that are *both the last row in a sequence, but also the first row of a following sequence*.
Since those need to be duplicated, I am assigning them two `IDx` values. We can then easily `unnest` the `IDx` column and come out with two rows.
In a second step, we basically just clean the data up by the rules you have given.

---

Step 1:
Identify for each row the corresponding IDx:
// UPDATE: filters out any value that does not reappear (if it does, it counts as a sequence) and any value that comes after the block of valid sequences

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df_idx <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  add_count(val) %>%
  filter(cumsum(n > 1) > 0) %>% # removes leading vals
  filter(rev(cumsum(rev(val == first(val))) > 0)) %>% # removes trailing vals
  select(-n) %>%
  mutate(
    is_sequence_first = case_when(
      row_number() == 1 ~ T,
      lag(val) != val & val == first(val) & lead(val) != val ~ T,
      T ~ F
    ),
    is_sequence_last = case_when(
      row_number() == n() ~ T,
      val == first(val) & lead(is_sequence_first) ~ T,
      lag(val) != first(val) & is_sequence_first ~ T,
      T ~ F
    ),
    IDx = case_when(
      is_sequence_first & is_sequence_last ~ map(cumsum(is_sequence_first), ~c(.x-1,.x)),
      T ~ as.list(cumsum(is_sequence_first))
    )
  ) %>%
  unnest(IDx) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Step 2:
Filter out duplicates in the block where there is only one IDx & exclude "illegal" (descending) sequences:

```
df_final <- df_idx %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(
    case_when(
      max(IDx) == 1 & row_number() == 1 ~ T,
      max(IDx) == 1 & val != lag(val) ~ T,
      max(IDx) > 1 ~ T,
      T ~ F
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(ID, IDx) %>%
  filter(
    any(val > first(val))
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-is_sequence_first, -is_sequence_last)
```

That gives the result you asked in your question.

Comment: Any solution that works here gets my upvote. This was a toughie! You also use `tidyr` and `purrr` here which is worth mentioning

Comment: true, I think I meant to write `tidyverse`-approach 

Comment: True, this is quite readable - thanks for the effort! Unfortunately, I've realised now my example lacked some complexity - namely, the first letter is not necessarily the initiating part of the sequence, and similarly for the last one, it is not necessarily part of the sequence if there is a cycle. Please see my update.

Comment: I've added two filter-lines in the first step that filter out any leading or trailing `val`s. essentially, the first letterthat appears more than once (either with or without an increasing sequence in between the two rows) starts a sequence. anything before is kicked out. also, anything after the last observation of that sequence-starting letter is kicked.

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I was really hoping for some shortcut approaches, but it seems there is no way around mapping all the indices of where values occur etc. I'll leave the question open for today, and if no other more concise/faster replies I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I was thinking of ways to accomplish this more elegantly with `purrr::reduce`, but then got a little lost along the way with all the edge cases...

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult. Getting the `val` column is actually fairly straightforward. It's getting the ID numbers to match that's difficult.

The following is neither quick nor pretty, but it works. The algorithm you describe seems a little too complex to have a neat solution, but I could be wrong...

```r
IDs <- split(as.integer(factor(input$val)), input$ID)

vals <- unlist(lapply(IDs, function(x) {
  y <- which(x == x[1])
  a <- lapply(seq_along(y)[-1], function(z) {
    z <- x[seq(y[z-1], y[z])]
    if(length(z) == 2 | any(z < z[1])) return(NULL)
    z <- levels(factor(input$val))[z[c(which(diff(z) != 0), length(z))]]
    names(z) <- rep(names(IDs)[sapply(IDs, identical, x)], length(z))
    z
    })
  setNames(a, seq_along(a))
  }))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = as.numeric(gsub(".*\\.(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(vals))),
                  val = vals, row.names = seq_along(vals),
                  IDx = as.numeric(gsub("^.*\\.(\\d+)\\..*$", "\\1", names(vals))))

output <- `rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df2, df2$ID), 
                      function(x) within(x, IDx <- as.numeric(factor(IDx))))),
             seq(nrow(df2)))
```

Giving us:

```r
output
#>    ID val IDx
#> 1   1   c   1
#> 2   1   d   1
#> 3   1   c   1
#> 4   2   b   1
#> 5   2   c   1
#> 6   2   d   1
#> 7   2   b   1
#> 8   2   b   2
#> 9   2   c   2
#> 10  2   b   2
#> 11  3   a   1
#> 12  3   b   1
#> 13  3   a   1
#> 14  3   a   2
#> 15  3   b   2
#> 16  3   a   2
```

---

**Data**

```r
input <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), val = c("c", "c", 
"d", "d", "c", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"a", "b", "a", "b", "f", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan, this is still far more neat than anything I would have imagined. However, unfortunately I've just realised the example I gave lacks some additional complexity - namely, the initiating letter of the sequence is not necessarily the first one; please see my update.